# colour bins of histogram in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, geom-bar

I want to plot a barplot like in figure. I want each bin to be coloured based on the sum of the value in the other columns.
[image]. I made a reproducible example here.

```
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)

values= replicate(4, diff(c(0, sort(runif(92)), 1)))
 colnames(values) = c("A","B","C","D")
 counts = sample(10:100, 93, replace=T)
 df = data.frame(cbind(values,"count"=counts))
 mdf = melt(df,id="count")

 mdf = mdf %>%
  mutate(binCounts = cut(count, breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 5)))



  plot = ggplot(mdf) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=binCounts, fill=variable)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, hjust=1))

print(plot)
```

I want the count on the y axis. For each bar I want to plot the proportion of the data from the column A B C and D. However with the above code it tends to plot the count of the variable rather than the sum.

Comment: Yes, `geom_bar` plots counts of observations. Use `geom_col`, supplying a y value (I'm guessing you want `y = count`) to your `aes` and see if that works.

Comment: @camille 'geom_col' helped but it also summed up the count exactly 4 times which I dont want.

Comment: Okay, so I think you need to do a little more data prep before plotting. Such as summing the counts within each bin and variable

Answer (score 0):

```
mdf %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(binCounts = cut(count, breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 5))) %>% 
  group_by(binCounts,variable) %>% 
  summarise(count = sum(count)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=binCounts,y = count, fill=variable)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, hjust=1))
```